# Copy one row column value to next row column

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have below scenario

```
Leave Date 10/05/2015-10/05/2015  10/10/2015-10/10/2015  20/10/2015-25/10/2015       
No of days         1                        1                5 
Closing Balance    50                       49               48
Opening Balance    49                       48               43
```

I need to copy opening balance value in closing balance column. I can not find the way out. kindly help me on this. Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Do you mean to say you are overwriting `Closing Balance`?  Did you try using an `UPDATE`?

Comment: Do you have an `ID` or column date of data type dates that distinguish each row form the other?

Comment: no i am using select statement to generate this output as i need to show this in report

Comment: Yes we have from date and to date to distinguish the rows

Comment: At least I feel like you should calculate this before doing to pivot (which you probably are using to get this layout)

Comment: Thank you  JamesZ for editing